# How to automate angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Tags: angularjs, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

**Problem :** trying to simulate drag drop in frontend that uses angular-drag-and-drop-lists  ([go to detailed description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039892/drag-drop-simulation-not-working-for-frontend-that-uses-angular-drag-and-drop-li))

**Tried :**

1.jquery-simulate:  Gives following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on
>   'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.

2.drag-drop-helper.js : click happens on item to be dragged

3.drag_to  : nothing happens

**Need some more suggestions .**

Thanks

jquery-simulate: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate

sorry not able to post link for drag_to and drag-drop-helper.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom event needed to adjusted like this :

```
  function createCustomEvent(type) {
 var event = new CustomEvent("CustomEvent", {"cancelable": true})
    event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null);
    event.dataTransfer = {
        data: {
        },
        setData: function(type,val) {
            this.data[type] = val
            this.types[0] = type
        }
        getData: function(type) {
            return this.data[type]
        },
        dropEffect: 'move',
        effectAllowed:'move',
        types: [],
        items: {},
        files:{}

    }

    return event
}
```

in [native js drag drop script](https://gist.github.com/druska/624501b7209a74040175) and then it works fine