# HTML5 DragDrop dataTransfer.types not set after event.dataTransfer.setData(mimeType, angular.toJson(item)) in chrome

Tags: drag-and-drop, dom-events, custom-events, angulardraganddroplists

I am using  druska/native_js_drag_and_drop_helper.js to automate [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists)

**Issue :**
 Even after `event.dataTransfer.setData(mimeType,angular.toJson(item))`

`dataTransfer.types` is not set or probably not allowed to read in dragstart and drop event

**Observation : during manual drag drop dragstart event**

```
dataTransfer {dropEffect: "none", effectAllowed: "move", items: DataTransferItemList, types: Array(1), files: FileList}
    dropEffect:"move"
    effectAllowed:"move"
    files:FileList
    items:DataTransferItemList
    types:Array(0)
    __proto__:DataTransfer

DataTransferItemList {0: DataTransferItem, length: 1}
    length: 0
    __proto__: DataTransferItemList

 DataTransferItem {kind: "string", type: "application/x-dnd"}
    kind: ""type: ""
    __proto__: DataTransferItem
```

**Observation:when using  custom event**

```
dataTransfer:Object
    data:Object
        application/x-dnd:"[{"id":"706","title":"Ab 2","drag":false,"selected":true}]"
        __proto__:Object
    dropEffect:"move"
    effectAllowed:"move"
    getData:function (type)
    setData:function (type,val)
    files:Object
    items:Object
    types:Array(0)
```

**I am using**

```
var event = new CustomEvent("CustomEvent", {"cancelable": true})
        event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null);
        event.dataTransfer = {
            data: {
            },
            setData: function(type,val) {
                this.data[type] = val
            },
            getData: function(type) {
                return this.data[type]
            },
            dropEffect: 'move',
            effectAllowed:'move',
            types: [],
            items:{},
            files:{}


        }
```

I am not able to initialize dataTransfer object.
 dataTransfer.items and  dataTransfer.types being read only property , i don't know how to correctly 
 initialize them .[MDN dataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automate angular-drag-and-drop-lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43109946/how-to-automate-angular-drag-and-drop-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was setData dint had code to set DataTransfer.types that was being used by angular-drag-and-drop-lists during drag drop.

```
        setData: function(type,val) {
            this.data[type] = val
            this.types[0] = type
        }
```

Above changes fixed the issue .Drag drop working fine now using native js