# correct way to initialize CustomEvent dataTransfer object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, custom-events

I am not getting   dataTransfer.types in custom event though in manual drag drop , types gets set to types: Array(1) . Can someone please correct me in initializing this dataTransfer object .(browser:chrome)

```
 function createCustomEvent(type) {
 var event = new CustomEvent("CustomEvent", {"cancelable": true})
    event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null);
    event.dataTransfer = {
        data: {
        },
        setData: function(type,val) {
            this.data[type] = val
        },
        getData: function(type) {
            return this.data[type]
        },
        dropEffect: 'move',
        effectAllowed:'move',
        types: [],
        items: {},
        files:{}

    }

    return event
}
```

[more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391567/html5-dragdrop-datatransfer-types-not-set-after-event-datatransfer-setdatamimet)

Answer (score 0):

Changed set data so that it also adds data type to types array as shown below :

```
        setData: function(type,val) {
            this.data[type] = val
            this.types[0] = type
        }
```

This fixed the issue and now proper drag drop is happening that uses angular js drag drop list that intenally uses html5 dnd api